# How to determine whether $R^{-1}$ is an equivalence relation to set $A$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose that $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on a nonempty set $A$.
(a) Either prove that $R\cup S$ is an equivalence relation on $A$ or give a counterexample to disprove it.
(b) Determine whether $R^{−1}$ is an equivalence relation on $A$.

I think I solved (a): let $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. 
Put $R = \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(1, 2),(2, 1)\}$ and $S = \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(2, 3),(3, 2)\}$.

Then $R$ and $S$ are equivalence relations on A.

We also have $R \cup S = \{(1, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 3),(3, 2)\}$. 
Thus $(1, 2),(2, 3) \in R \cup S$ but $(1, 3) \not\in R \cup S$, so that $R \cup S$ is not transitive. 
Therefore $R \cup S$ is not an equivalence relation on $$A.

But I'm stuck on part (b). can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have an equivalence relation $R$.  Then $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  Remember also that if $(a,b) \in R$, then $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$.

Since $R$ is reflexive, then $(a,a) \in R$.  Since $(a,a) \in R$, then $(a,a) \in R^{-1}$.  So if $R$ is reflexive, then $R^{-1}$ is reflexive as well.

Since $R$ is symmetric, then $(a,b) \in R \iff (b,a) \in R$.  Since $(a,b) \in R$, then what must be in $R^{-1}$?  Also, since $(b,a) \in R$, then what must be in $R^{-1}$?  Does this show that $R^{-1}$ is symmetric?

Transitivity will work very similarly but I'll leave the details to you.

Let me know if you need more assistance.

Comment: so since (a,b)∈R, (a,b)∈R^(−1) and since (b,a)∈R, (b,a)∈R^(−1) right? therefore R^(-1) is symmetric?

Comment: also can you start me off on the transitivity part?

Comment: To your first comment, no.  $(a,b) \in R$ doesn't mean $(a,b) \in R^{-1}$, and $(b,a) \in R$ doesn't mean $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$.  See my first pagraph in the answer again.

Comment: @rochelle, for transitivity, start with $(a,b), (b,c) \in R \implies (a,c) \in R$.  So since $(a,b) \in R$, then what's in $R^{-1}$?  Do similar reasoning for $(b,c)$ and $(a,c)$ and see if you can conclude anything about $R^{-1}$.

Comment: sorry i meant to write since (a,b)∈R, (b,a)∈R^(−1) and since (b,a)∈R, (a,b)∈R^(−1) is this correct?

Comment: and for transitivity Im confused at the concept. what is my goal?

Comment: @rochelle, yes, that's correct.  For transitivity your goal is to show that $R^{-1}$ is transitive.  Use what I wrote in my previous comment for getting started on transitivity and combine that with the fact that $(a,b) \in R$ implies $(b,a) \in R^{-1}$, and similarly for $(b,c)$ and $(a,c)$.  Then see if that gives you transitivity of $R^{-1}$.  It's basically the exact same idea as for symmetry (and for reflexivity but reflexivity is too simple to draw a useful parallel).